# Files piling up in Suave.io's _temporary_compressed_files folder

Tags: f#, suave

I'm using Suave.io as a web server in a shared hosting environment. I've noticed that files created in the `_temporary_compressed_files` folder are never getting deleted. The documentation says "Suave deletes these files once they are served, so their lifetime is usually less than a second," but this is not occurring and I cannot see anywhere in the Suave code where this is implemented. What can I do to make sure these files get deleted in a timely fashion?

Comment: Report it as a potential bug. You're likely to get better help on such a library specific issue on the issue tracker anyway.

Comment: Good suggestion. I created https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/issues/655. We'll see what happens.